# How to implement MD5 on UDP ECHO SERVER file AND UDP ECHO CLIENT file?

Tags: c, md5

I try to put the md5 function into udpcli01.c file. Then compile $ cc -o udpcli01 udpcli01.c -lcrypto.
There is a fatal error :udpcli01.c:1:17: fatal error: unp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "unp.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.

how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

The `MD5_Init`, `MD5_Update`, and `MD5_Final` functions are part of the "libcrypto" library (which is part of OpenSSL). Link against it by passing `-lcrypto` while linking your application.